# Read HTML file to generate data using javascript

Tags: javascript

I got to read a number of HTML files, get its tags content and generate a report using these contents (e.g day1.html has Simon, I need to read day1.html file, and get 'author' div content  which is 'Simon' and generate my own report using this data). How can I do it using Javascript?
any help is highly appreciated.
Many thanks.
An

Comment: Client-side JavaScript accessing HTML files on a web-server, or server-side JavaScript accessing files from the file system, or...?

Comment: it is server-side java script. yesterday my friend suggested me using AJAX, still working on searching :(

Comment: If it's server-side JS (node.js?) you wouldn't use Ajax: Ajax is a way for JS in the browser to make a request to the web-server without reloading the current page. Is a request from a web browser involved at all in your requirement?

Comment: My problem is: I am about to make news blog page for my project, We have a html(or xml) file called "blog.html(or .xml)", this file defines title, author, content for each post of the blog(like <DIV id="author">Simon</DIV> <DIV id="title">New blog</DIV> <DIV id="content">Content bla bla bla</DIV> , webadmin can also update this file later). My job is to read this file, get details and out put to jsp page.
many thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not adverse to using jQuery you can use [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to load and parse an HTML document via JavaScript:

```
jQuery.get('day1.html', function(html)) {
  var author_div_text_content = jQuery('DIV#author', html).text(); 
}
```

A sample working on the jsFiddle web site:

http://jsfiddle.net/KCxDp/

Comment: I ll try to work on this way you showed me, yesterday my friend suggested me using ajax and I am still googling it. maybe yr method would work out.many tks.